# Using a choose when to make conditional with param for apply templates call XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, biztalk

I'm in a situation where I need to send a parameters based on a certain condition. I tried using a choose-when element inside the apply templates element, but that is not allowed.

The apply templates element with the parameter:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Header/Amounts/Totals/TotalLineAmount[string(text())]" mode="MOALoop">
    <xsl:with-param name="qualifier" select="'203'">
```

This is my choose-when:

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="imdQualifier != ''">
              <xsl:value-of select="$imdQualifier"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$qualifier"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
```

If imdQualifier != '', then the param should be $imdQualifier, otherwise it should be 203.

How can I implement this logic inside an apply templates element?

Comment: Why can't you use the Mapper?  This is a pretty trivial operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Header/Amounts/Totals/TotalLineAmount[string(text())]" mode="MOALoop">
   <xsl:with-param name="qualifier">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="imdQualifier != ''">
          <xsl:value-of select="$imdQualifier"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'203'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```